# Modify Magento Subtotal Calculation: Tier prices

Tags: magento

I am using Tier Prices and have a set price for quantities that fall between 1 and 4 and a per item price for anything over 4.

I want to modify my cart to have a set price for items where Qty >= 1 && Qty <=4

How do I do that?

Here is the item i testing this with: http://stjamestutorials.com/ppptransportation/index.php/mayfield-falls-tours-negril-jamaica-tours.html

Answer (score 0):

Try and create an observer for this event:

```
catalog_product_get_final_price
```

which is found in the class :

```
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php
```

The event comes with the product and the qty, so you can write your logic and then set your custom price in the `final_price` attribute of the product.